# How can I "compile" an HTML template but not "execute" it?

Tags: ajax, go, html-templates

I'm using Go HTML templates and when you run this function it sends the data to the client, but I would like to store that data in a variable and send it to the client later. How can this be achieved?

```
func (t *Template) ExecuteTemplate(wr io.Writer, name string, data any) error
```

This is for use in an AJAX response. I know on the  client side I could simply parse the `xhr.responseText`, but I need to send some other variables with it.

Comment: Write it to a `bytes.Buffer` instead of the HTTP writer.

Comment: I get an error: `cannot use variable of type bytes.Buffer as io.Writer value in argument to templates.ExecuteTemplate: bytes.Buffer does not implement io.Writer (method Write has pointer receiver).`

Comment: Hey nevermind I just needed to make the `bytes.Buffer` a pointer. testing now

Comment: This is the solution, thanks. If you want to leave an answer below I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a buffer:

```
buf:=bytes.Buffer{}
t.ExecuteTemplate(&buf,"name",data)
```

Then you can use `buf.Bytes()`, or `buf.String()`.